# Add element to XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, lotus-notes

This is the XML I have exported from a Lotus Notes database:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database xmlns="http://www.lotus.com/dxl" path="CN=ATRVSIC1/OU=RVS/O=Raiffeisen Sbg.!!notesent\frzld\test.nsf" type="standard" title="test" uselz1="true" version="8.5" nourlopen="false" replicaid="C1257D2B002A37BB" requiressl="false" multilingual="false" maintainunread="true" multidbindexed="false" logtransactions="true" advancedtemplate="false" allowstoredforms="true" savelastaccessed="false" showinopendialog="true" allowsoftdeletion="false" increasemaxfields="false" allowdesignlocking="false" imageloadsdeferred="true" maintenanceversion="2.4" markmodifiedunread="true" overwritefreespace="false" singlecopytemplate="false" allowdocumentlocking="false" optimizetablebitmaps="false" usejavascriptinpages="true" allowbackgroundagents="true" allowheadlinemonitors="true" allowspecialhierarchy="true" unicodestandardsorting="false" allowexternalconnections="false" copyprofiledocswithdesign="false">
<databaseinfo dbid="C1257D2B002A37BB" diskspace="53215232" odsversion="43" percentused="11.0086976600985" numberofdocuments="52"><datamodified><datetime dst="true">20160623T092148,11+02</datetime></datamodified><designmodified><datetime dst="true">20160624T081402,68+02</datetime></designmodified></databaseinfo>
<fulltextsettings size="11670496" update="immediate" breakat="words" casesensitive="false" attachmenttype="rawtextonly" includeattachments="false" includeencryptedfields="true"><lastindexed><datetime dst="false">20160623T081159,12+00</datetime></lastindexed></fulltextsettings>
<launchsettings><noteslaunch frameset="Main" whenopened="openframeset"/></launchsettings>
<form name="DynamicFields" type="document" recalc="false" default="false" inherit="false" private="false" mailable="false" versions="none" anonymous="false" noreplace="false" storeform="false" useapplet="false" editonopen="false" inheritdoc="none" contextpane="hide" nofocusonf6="false" treatashtml="false" nofieldindex="false" publicaccess="false" readingorder="lefttoright" allowautosave="false" manualversion="false" signdocuments="false" conflictaction="createconflicts" noinitialfocus="false" designerversion="8.5.2" nofieldexchange="false" renderpassthrough="true">
<noteinfo unid="F6A625845C3510AAC1257FDB001A6F04" noteid="34e" sequence="14">
<created><datetime dst="true">20160623T064843,56+02</datetime></created>
<modified><datetime dst="true">20160624T070923,11+02</datetime></modified>
<revised><datetime dst="true">20160624T070923,10+02</datetime></revised>
<lastaccessed><datetime dst="true">20160624T070923,11+02</datetime></lastaccessed>
<addedtofile><datetime dst="true">20160623T064843,85+02</datetime></addedtofile></noteinfo>
<updatedby><name>CN=Daniel Lesiak/OU=RVS/O=Raiffeisen Sbg.</name></updatedby>
<wassignedby><name>CN=Daniel Lesiak/OU=RVS/O=Raiffeisen Sbg.</name></wassignedby>
<globals><code event="options"><lotusscript>Option Public
Use "DynamicFields"

</lotusscript></code></globals>
<actionbar align="left" bgcolor="#f0f0f0" bordercolor="black" useappletinbrowser="false" showdefaultrightclickitems="true">
<actionbuttonstyle bgcolor="#f0f0f0" textalign="left" widthtype="default" heighttype="default" margintype="default" showdropdown="false" displayborder="onmouseover" internalmargin="0"/><font color="system"/><border color="black" style="solid" width="0px 0px 1px" dropshadow="false" insidewidth="0" outsidewidth="0" dropshadowwidth="12px"/>
<action hide="" align="left" title="Speichern" showinbar="true" showinmenu="true" displaytype="button" graphicalign="left" readingorder="lefttoright" onlyiconinbar="false" publishonolelaunch="false" showinrightbuttonmenu="false"><code event="click"><formula>@Command([FileSave])</formula></code></action></actionbar>
<body><richtext>
<pardef id="1" hide="" list="none" align="left" newpage="false" spaceafter="1" linespacing="1" spacebefore="1" readingorder="lefttoright"/>
<par def="1"/>
<par def="1"><button edge="system" type="normal" width="2in" bgcolor="system" default="false" maxlines="1" wraptext="true" widthtype="maximum" readingorder="lefttoright">Create Field<code event="click"><lotusscript>Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim w As New NotesUIWorkspace

    Call CreateField(w.CurrentDocument.Document, "Daniel")
End Sub</lotusscript></code></button></par>
<par def="1"><field kind="editable" name="Herbert" sign="false" type="text" protected="false" allowtabout="false" defaultfocus="false" storelocally="false" showdelimiters="true" allowmultivalues="false" useappletinbrowser="false" dataconnectionfield="data" computeaftervalidation="false"/><compositedata type="98" nexttype="222" prevtype="65418" afterparcount="6" containertype="65418" afterbegincount="3" aftercontainercount="1">
Yg4BAIQAAAAAAAAAAAA=
</compositedata></par>
<par def="1"><field kind="computed" name="Sieglinde" sign="false" type="text" protected="false" allowtabout="false" defaultfocus="false" storelocally="false" showdelimiters="true" allowmultivalues="false" useappletinbrowser="false" dataconnectionfield="data" computeaftervalidation="false"><code event="defaultvalue"><formula>"Sieglinde"</formula></code></field><compositedata type="98" nexttype="222" prevtype="65418" afterparcount="6" containertype="65418" afterbegincount="3" aftercontainercount="1">
Yg4BAIQAAAAAAAAAAAA=
</compositedata></par>
<par def="1"/></richtext></body>
<item name="$$ScriptName" seal="false" sign="true" names="false" sealed="false" authors="false" readers="false" summary="false" placeholder="false"><text>DynamicFields</text></item></form>
</database>
```

Looks very messy, but that's how I get it exported. Now what I want to do is to add another "par" element right after the element "pardef" using a XSL-file. This is my approach:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="database/form/body/richtext/pardef">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:element name="par">
            <xsl:attribute name="def">2</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything but copy the already existent XML. My template to add another element doesn't apply.
Why is it not applying and how can I get my desired result?

Comment: Try `<xsl:template match="pardef">` ?

Comment: @MariaDeleva same result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a namespace issue. Right at the start of your XML you have this...

```
 <database xmlns="http://www.lotus.com/dxl"
```

This means the `database` element, and all descendants elements, are in this namespace. An element in a namespace, like `pardef` is not the same as an element that is not in a space, even if it is also called `pardef`.

To handle this, you just have to declare and use the namespace in your XSLT too.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:dxl="http://www.lotus.com/dxl" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dxl:database/dxl:form/dxl:body/dxl:richtext/dxl:pardef">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:element name="par" namespace="http://www.lotus.com/dxl">
            <xsl:attribute name="def">2</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the prefix used (`dxl` in this case) is not important. It is the namespace URI (http://www.lotus.com/dxl) that must match between XML and XSLT.

Note you maybe change the template match to just `<xsl:template match="dxl:pardef">`. You don't need to specify the full path, unless there were `pardef` elements are different levels that you didn't want to transform.

Also note, you can also change `<xsl:element name="par" namespace="http://www.lotus.com/dxl">` to just this....

```
<dxl:par test="2" />
```

Comment: This is the way to go, thanks for that. However, this gets me an element looking like this: `<par xmlns:dxl="http://www.lotus.com/dxl" def="1">`. Can I get rid of the `xmlns:dxl` attribute?

Comment: It probably depends on the XSLT processor how it is rendered. Certainly when I tried (at http://www.xslfiddle.net/) using `<xsl:element name="par" namespace="http://www.lotus.com/dxl">` it renders as just `<par def="2"/>`. However, despite is looking odd, semantically it is exactly the same as far as the XML document is concerned. The namespace prefix is not important. In both cases you have  `par` element that belongs to the namespace `http://www.lotus.com/dxl`.